# Powershell singleton and $this behavior

Tags: powershell, oop, singleton

I am in the throes of a major refactor and PS OOP education, with the current topic being singletons. I have some program status data that I want to make available in a singleton, and I am seeing some odd behavior.

This works for the first two Write-Lines, but then hangs on the third one, that references the second class.

```
class PxStatus {
    static [PxStatus] $singleton = $null
    [string]$Context = 'machine'
    [datetime]$StartTime = (Get-Date)

    static [PxStatus] Get() {
        if ([PxStatus]::singleton -eq $null) {
            [PxStatus]::singleton = [PxStatus]::new()
        }

        return [PxStatus]::singleton
    }
}

class pxLogFile {
    # Properties
    static [pxLogFile] $singleton = $null
    [string] $nameSeed = "PxTools $(([PxStatus]::Get()).Context) context"
    [string] $path = "$env:TEMP\$(([pxLogFile]::Get()).nameSeed) $((get-date).toString('yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss')).log"

    static [pxLogFile] Get() {
        if ([pxLogFile]::singleton -eq $null) {
            [pxLogFile]::singleton = [pxLogFile]::new()

        return [pxLogFile]::singleton
    }
}



CLS
Write-Host "$(([PxStatus]::Get()).Context)"
Write-Host "$(([PxStatus]::Get()).StartTime)"
Write-Host "$(([pxLogFile]::Get()).path)"
```

However, if I address the path in the constructor, like this, it works.

```
class PxStatus {
    static [PxStatus] $singleton = $null
    [string]$Context = 'machine'
    [datetime]$StartTime = (Get-Date)

    static [PxStatus] Get() {
        if ([PxStatus]::singleton -eq $null) {
            [PxStatus]::singleton = [PxStatus]::new()

            #([PxStatus]::singleton).Context = 'machine'
            #([PxStatus]::singleton).StartTime = Get-Date
        }

        return [PxStatus]::singleton
    }
}

class pxLogFile {
    # Properties
    static [pxLogFile] $singleton = $null
    [string] $nameSeed = "PxTools $(([PxStatus]::Get()).Context) context"
    [string] $path = $null

    static [pxLogFile] Get() {
        if ([pxLogFile]::singleton -eq $null) {
            [pxLogFile]::singleton = [pxLogFile]::new()

            ([pxLogFile]::singleton).Path = "$env:TEMP\$(([pxLogFile]::Get()).nameSeed) $((get-date).toString('yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss')).log"
        }

        return [pxLogFile]::singleton
    }
}



CLS
Write-Host "$(([PxStatus]::Get()).Context)"
Write-Host "$(([PxStatus]::Get()).StartTime)"
Write-Host "$(([pxLogFile]::Get()).path)
```

I assume the issue is with accessing a property in the same singleton, as I do for the nameSeed. Alternatively I can also use this in the property definition.

```
[string] $path = "$env:TEMP\$($this.nameSeed) $((get-date).toString('yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss')).log"
```

Which to be honest is more readable anyway. I am just wondering exactly what is happening with that first one that causes the failure? Am I creating some sort of weird loop condition by not using `$this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[pxLogFile]::Get()` call nested inside

```
[string] $path = "$env:TEMP\$(([pxLogFile]::Get()).nameSeed) $((get-date).toString('yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss')).log"
```

causes an infinite recursion that eventually causes a stack overflow.

Simply directly refer to `$nameSeed`, the other static property, in the initialization of `$path`:

```
class pxLogFile {
    # Properties
    static [pxLogFile] $singleton = $null
    [string] $nameSeed = "PxTools $(([PxStatus]::Get()).Context) context"
    # Refer to $nameSeed instead of to [pxLogFile]::Get()).nameSeed
    [string] $path = "$env:TEMP\$($nameSeed) $((get-date).toString('yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss')).log"

    static [pxLogFile] Get() {
        if ($null -eq [pxLogFile]::singleton) {
            [pxLogFile]::singleton = [pxLogFile]::new()
        }
        return [pxLogFile]::singleton
    }
}
```